# Why is my Android lib dir symlink incorrect?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm making an Android app whose native NDK code dynamically links some `.so` shared library files with `dlopen()` (if you're interested, it's the OpenNI2 camera library that first detects which camera model is attached and then loads an `.so` file for that model).

I've placed these libraries in my `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/` directory (for my phone running API version 19 on ARM) and `app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/` directory (for my tablet running API version 23 on Intel x86_64).

On the ARM, everything works fine, and the symlink to the `lib` directory containing my `.so` files is correct:

```
# ls -l /data/data/com.example/
drwxrwx--x u0_a175  u0_a175           2015-09-02 00:10 app_execdir
drwxrwx--x u0_a175  u0_a175           2015-09-19 22:39 cache
lrwxrwxrwx install  install           2015-09-20 02:30 lib -> /data/app-lib/com.example-1

# ls -l /data/app-lib/com.example-1
-rwxr-xr-x system   system     409940 2015-10-20 02:30 gdbserver
-rwxr-xr-x system   system     308532 2015-10-18 01:06 libOpenNI2.so
```

However, on the Intel I see:

```
# ls -l /data/data/com.example/                                 
drwxrwx--x u0_a65   u0_a65            2015-09-20 00:41 app_execdir
drwxrwx--x u0_a65   u0_a65            2015-09-20 00:41 cache
lrwxrwxrwx install  install           2015-09-20 00:41 lib -> /data/app-lib/com.example

# ls -l /data/app-lib/com.example
/data/app-lib/com.example: No such file or directory
```

What's going on here? Why does the `lib` symlink point to a directory that doesn't exist?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense for the symlink...

However .so files shouldn't be in /data/app-lib/ with Android 21+. 
Can you find your libs inside /data/app/com.example-1/lib/x86_64 ?

You can read *legacyNativeLibraryDir* from `dumpsys package packages` to know where the libs should be placed.